# "Proxy" Capture of $stderr and $stdout for DB Storage

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, delayed-job

I am trying to store the `stderr` and `stdout` in our database for the future debugging purpose of our background processes. I want also the capture to be transparent like a proxy, by that I mean that I want to still have the `stderr` and the `stdout` outputed to the regular logger in plus of our database one.

I have this kind of code:

```
class Message

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :stdout
  field :stderr

  def enable_capture_output
    @previous_stderr, $stderr = $stderr, StringIO.new
    @previous_stdout, $stdout = $stdout, StringIO.new
  end

  def disable_and_save_captured_output
    self.stdout = $stdout.string
    self.stderr = $stderr.string
    $stderr = @previous_stderr
    $stdout = @previous_stdout
  end

end
```

But it doesn't work that well. :(

Using: Rails 3.2.11 and Mongoid 3.0.23 with DelayedJob

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work that well" means.  Does it work at all?  What goes wrong?  Is it that you're just forgetting to call `self.save`?

Comment: I am saving latter, this is working! I just want to see debug information while I am firing my method and not wait to be a the end and that the record is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it sounds like your problem is that you're not seeing the results stream to the database as they're happening.  But you're also not saving your document to the database except at the end.  So...  if you want to see the results in the database before the end of the process, you'll have to write to the database incrementally, before the end of the process.

I recommend looking at mongo's [`$push` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) which you can use to efficiently add more results to a document without rewriting the entire document.  You use it with the `update` command which you can use through [moped](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html) which underlies mongoid.

Alternatively, you can save yourself a lot of work by using a log aggregator service like [logentries](http://logentries.com) or [loggly](http://loggly.com/).